# How to use PXRestrictor

Tags: acumatica

I've been playing around with this PXRestrictor and I'm a bit lost how to use this on an unrelated table on the current graph. So in Sales Order I'd like to limit the items on the lookup screen. I'd like the items I added on the ARSalesPrice table **NOT** to appear in the lookup screen. I overridden the SOline InventoryID's attribute as follows

```
[SOLineInventoryItem(Filterable=true)]
[PXDefault()]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<ARSalesPrice.inventoryID,Equal<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>), "RESTRICTION ACTIVATED !!!")]
protected virtual void SOLine_InventoryID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
```

And I'm getting an error :

[image]

I tried both Equal and NotEqual condition but I think the issue is with ARSalesPrice not being part of the graph. What am I doing wrong ?

TIA

Comment: Your error is saying that you have not ARSalesPrice table in the select part of your query and you **can't** use it in the where condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only utilize a restrictor that utilizes the DACs in the selector on that same field. Most likely in your example `ARSalesPrice` is not in the selector on `SOLine.InventoryID` and as a result you cannot restrict by this dac.

You can actually see two PXRestrictors in use in the attribute for `SOLineInventoryItemAttribute`:

```
[PXDBInt()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.noSales>>), IN.Messages.ItemCannotSale)]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>>), PM.Messages.ReservedForProject)]
public class SOLineInventoryItemAttribute : CrossItemAttribute
{
//...
}
```

The restrictor basically adds a where condition to the base selector for the results and if the condition of the restrictor is true then the error message provided is displayed to the user. In your example it looks like you are trying to perform some type of where join which will not work the way you have it. Typical use is to check for a field value against some type of constant value (Ex: item marked as not for sale `Where<InventoryItem.itemStatus, NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.noSales>>`).

To accomplish what you need you have to completely change the base selector (overriding the selector with your own) and use the restrictor as a condition of the your new selector tables (but your existing restrictor in your example will not work).

Using a restrictor is nice to not limit values in the base selector that would otherwise return a value not found error if the where condition was in the selector. Moving a condition to a restrictor lets the user know the value is an actual value, however isn't allowed for X condition where X is your message in your PXRestrictor.

I believe there is an `Exists<>` bql command that might give you a true value if the join results indicate there is a record in the ARSalesPrice table. Look in Acumatica source for examples.

For reference here is another example on the Sales Order (`SOOrder`) dac which shows both the selector and multiple restrictors:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search5<SOOrderType.orderType,
    InnerJoin<SOOrderTypeOperation, On<SOOrderTypeOperation.orderType, Equal<SOOrderType.orderType>, And<SOOrderTypeOperation.operation, Equal<SOOrderType.defaultOperation>>>,
    LeftJoin<SOSetupApproval, On<SOOrderType.orderType, Equal<SOSetupApproval.orderType>>>>,
    Aggregate<GroupBy<SOOrderType.orderType>>>))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderTypeOperation.iNDocType, NotEqual<INTranType.transfer>, Or<FeatureInstalled<FeaturesSet.warehouse>>>), ErrorMessages.ElementDoesntExist, typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderType.requireAllocation, NotEqual<True>, Or<AllocationAllowed>>), ErrorMessages.ElementDoesntExist, typeof(SOOrderType.orderType))]
[PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<SOOrderType.active,Equal<True>>), null)]
```

You can apply multiple restrictors for different conditions. Here you can see the PXSelector statement with the additional restrictors.